# API Platform: How to normalize a collection of embedded entities in GraphQL?

Tags: symfony, graphql, api-platform.com

I'm trying to make a collection of subresources selectable in GraphQL (with pagination). I'd like to be able to query:

```
query {
  getA(id: '/api/A/1') {
    aId
    subresources {
      totalCount
      pageInfo {
        endCursor
        startCursor
        hasNextPage
        hasPreviousPage
      }
      edges {
        node {
          bId
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and get the result:

```json
{
  aId: 1,
  subresources: {
    "totalCount": XX,
    "pageInfo": {
      "endCursor": "MQ==",
      "startCursor": "MA==",
      "hasNextPage": true,
      "hasPreviousPage": false
    },
    edges: [
      {
        node: {
          bId: 11
        }
      },
      {
        node: {
          bId: 12
        }
      },
      {
        node: {
          bId: 13
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm not using Doctrine at all- I'm using custom data providers. The problem I'm encountering is that even when I return an `A` entity from `DataProvider::getItem()` that has an array of `B` subresources, I get an empty array for `subresources` in GraphQL. I get the correct data in REST though.

I'm following the instructions given in [SymfonyCasts](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform-extending/collections-readable-link#play) and I found a related [API Platform issue](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/606), but I'm still having no luck.

I traced through API Platform core and I think it has to do with how the entity is normalized in GraphQL. Specifically, an empty array is returned in [`ItemNormalizer::normalizeCollectionOfRelations()`](https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/ff3aab5b196709c721960c0bb4f1d52759af737d/src/GraphQl/Serializer/ItemNormalizer.php#L89-L96). However, there's a comment saying "to-many are handled directly by the GraphQL resolver" but I'm not sure what that refers to.

Here's the entity code.

```php
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiProperty;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

#[ApiResource(
   graphql: ['item_query', 'collection_query', 'create', 'update', 'delete'],
   collectionOperations: ['get', 'post'],
   itemOperations: ['get', 'put', 'patch', 'delete'],
   normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['read']],
   denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['write']],
)]
class A {
   #[ApiProperty(identifier: true)]
   #[Groups(['read', 'write'])]
   public ?int $aId = null,

   /** @var B[] */
   #[ApiProperty(readableLink: true, writableLink: true)]
   #[Groups(['read', 'write'])]
   public $subresources = []
}
```

And:

```php
#[ApiResource(
   graphql: ['item_query', 'collection_query', 'create', 'update', 'delete'],
   collectionOperations: ['get', 'post'],
   itemOperations: ['get', 'put', 'patch', 'delete'],
   normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['read']],
   denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['write']],
)]
class B {
   #[ApiProperty(identifier: true)]
   #[Groups(['read', 'write'])]
   public ?int $bId = null,
}
```

My ADataProvider:

```php
   public function getItem(string $resourceClass, $id, string $operationName = null, array $context = []): A {
      $bs = $this->bDataProvider->getCollection(B::class, null, []);
      return new A(123, $bs);
   }
```

My BDataProvider:

```php
   /**
    * @return ArrayPaginator<B>
    */
   public function getCollection(string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null, array $context = []): ArrayPaginator {
      return ArrayPaginator::fromList([new B(11), new B(12), new B(13)]);
   }
```

`ArrayPaginator` implements `IteratorAggregate` and `PaginatorInterface`.

Specifically I see this error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "debugMessage": "Collection returned by the collection data provider must implement ApiPlatform\\Core\\DataProvider\\PaginatorInterface or ApiPlatform\\Core\\DataProvider\\PartialPaginatorInterface.",
      "message": "Internal server error",
      "extensions": {
        "category": "internal"
      },
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 29,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "a",
        "b"
      ],
      "trace": [
        {
          "file": "/homedir/core/src/GraphQl/Resolver/Stage/SerializeStage.php",
          "line": 100,
          "call": "ApiPlatform\\Core\\GraphQl\\Resolver\\Stage\\SerializeStage::serializeCursorBasedPaginatedCollection(array(0), array(5), array(6))"
        },
```

TLDR: How does one use annotations (or YAML) to make attributes that are collections of subresources selectable in GraphQL?

Any help/ideas are appreciated, thanks for reading!

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue where my collections are being populated correctly but they are empty in the GraphQL response. All my data is coming from external API's and there is no DB attached to the API Platform installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution: the `ApiPlatform\Core\DataProvider\SubresourceDataProviderInterface` needs to be implemented by the `BDataProvider`.

It gets used in the [ReadStage](https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/f48902ebd3783ca1c870744b3ec6963d4dac8a88/src/Core/GraphQl/Resolver/Stage/ReadStage.php#L171-L188) of api platform's graphql resolver. Surprisingly, it's found nowhere in the REST resolver, so this won't get called on a REST request.

The only method that needs to be implemented is `getSubresource()`. My basic first implementation looks like this:

```
public function getSubresource(string $resourceClass, array $identifiers, array $context, string $operationName = null) {
  if ($context['collection']) {
     return $this->getCollection($resourceClass, $operationName, $context);
  }
  $id = // get your id from $identifiers;
  return $this->getItem($resourceClass, $id, $operationName, $context);
}
```

This isn't found in the docs unfortunately, but there are a few pulls ([1](https://github.com/api-platform/docs/pull/446), [2](https://github.com/api-platform/docs/pull/1454)) open to add it.